# How can I prevent the cursor from blinking in Elvis in Xterm?

Tags: terminal, cursor, elvis

The cursor of vi (elvis) keep blinking under on a Raspberry Pi with the Rasbian distribution. It occurs with Xterm, not the xfce-terminal. On the computer or via ssh session.

With the same setup (.elvisrc, etc) there's no such blinking with Elvis under Xterm with a Slackware.

It blink only in "command" mode, not "input" mode.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You mentioned both a vimrc and Elvis (which is a Vi clone that uses a different config file), can you please confirm which one it is? Please include output of something like `vi --version` or perhaps what your package manager (dpkg?) tells you about your Elvis (or Vim?) package.

Comment: I mean .elvisrc :) 
Here the version:

elvis 2.2.1-prerelease

Comment: Awesome... Please [edit] the question to include more details. That should help people who might want to answer it find all the details in one place and not have to go through the comments...

Comment: It's a version that I've compiled after I get rid of the one which came with the distribution.

Comment: Did you try adding `xterm.vt100.blink: false` and/or `XTerm*cursorBlink: false` to your `~/.Xresources`?

Comment: Yes, even launching xterm with +bc options. I launch xterm on the Slackware and run Elvis, no blinking. With de same xterm ssh to the Raspberry pi, no blinking until I run Elvis :(